# How do you search on String fields in google appengine datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, search, properties, google-cloud-datastore

I have a google appengine project that where I am storing users.

```
public void createUser(String loginId, String password) {
    Entity e = new Entity("User");
    e.setProperty("loginId", loginId);
    e.setProperty("password", specialPasswordEncryptor(password));
    ds.put(e);
}
```

Later I want to search for the User Entity by loginId when someone tries to login.  But the problem is String properties are not indexed.

In the past I used add filter like this and it worked:

```
public Entity findUserByLoginId(String loginId) {

    Query query = new Query("User").addFilter("loginId",Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL, loginId);   
    Entity eUser = datastore.prepare(query).asSingleEntity();
    return eUser;
}
```

However addFilter is deprecated.  I've tried other ways of doing this but keep running into the problem that String properties are not indexed so I cannot search on loginId.

Can someone point me in the right direction on this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

String properties certainly [can be indexed](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/indexes#Java_Indexes_and_properties), unless they're longer than 1500 characters ([javadoc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Text)).

To filter, you want to use [`setFilter()`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Filters), like this:

```
    Query query = new Query("User").setFilter(
            new FilterPredicate("loginId", FilterOperator.EQUAL, loginId));
```